# Bootstrap Columns gap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m building a dashboard, and I´m using this template (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) available by bootstrap that works fine,  in the left side bar menu, I want to have a smaller width, but when I put a fixed width the content of the right doesn't resize, so I get a huge gap in the middle between the sidebar and content.

I tried to remove the columns padding, but doesnt make difference, I need to re size the right column when the left one (sidebar) get smaller.

Comment: What classes did you use to resize the left nav ? inside the core Div for the content area, change the offset from `2` to a `1` example; `col-md-offset-1`

Comment: @andre3wap the problem is still there, if i change im stuck with the width that is given with the columns, i need to create a custom left fixed width column